# How to dynamically create ec2 instances using a Terraform for_each

Tags: terraform

I am attempting to dynamically create ec2 instances using a `for_each`. But I am getting this error:

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   with aws_instance.ec2-instance,
│   on main.tf line 76, in resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance":
│   76: resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
│
│ "instance_type": one of `instance_type,launch_template` must be specified
```

Here is the Terraform:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

variable "instance_name" {
  description = "Value of the Name tag for the EC2 instance"
  type        = string
  default     = "ChangedName"
}

variable "aws_region" {
  description = "AWS Region"
  type        = string
  default     = "eu-west-2"
}

variable "instance_size_small" {
  description = "Instance size small"
  type        = string
  default     = "t3.micro"
}

variable "redundant_count" {
  description         = "Default redundancy - base number of instances to create for redundant services"
  type                = number
  default             = 1
}

variable "ami" {
  description = "Ubuntu 20.04 AMI"
  type        = string
  default     = "ami-0015a39e4b7c0966f"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "sandbox"
  region  = var.aws_region
}

variable "environment_name" {
  description         = "Environment Name"
  type                = string
  default             = "dev"
}

variable "client_name" {
  description         = "Client Name"
  type                = string
  default             = "sandbox"
}

variable "instances" {
  description = "Map of modules names to configuration."
  type        = map
  default     = {
    testing-sandbox-dev = {
      instance_count          = 2,
      instance_type           = "t3.micro",
      environment             = "dev"
    },
    testing-sandbox-test = {
      instance_count          = 1,
      instance_type           = "t3.micro",
      environment             = "test"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
  ami                = var.ami

  for_each           = var.instances

  tags = {
    Name = "testing-${var.instances.index}.${var.environment_name}.${var.client_name}"
    client = var.client_name
    environment = var.environment_name
  }
}
```

`instance_type` is one of the keys defined in the map being iterated on. So why is Terraform not picking it up?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct error msg? It does not seem to be created by the code you provided.

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the question to include all code.

Comment: So you want 3 instances created? Two dev and 1 test?

Comment: That's correct @Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined an `instance_type` argument inside the `resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance"` block, which is where Terraform is reporting the error.

You'll need to write out each argument you want to set with an expression which tells Terraform how you'd like to set it. If you want to set to values derived from your `for_each` elements then you can write it like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
  for_each = var.instances

  ami           = var.ami
  instance_type = each.value.instance_type

  tags = {
    Name = "testing-${var.instances.index}.${var.environment_name}.${var.client_name}"
    client = var.client_name
    environment = var.environment_name
  }
}
```

It seems like you also have another question about how to create `each.value.instance_count` instances from each element of this mapping, but I think that'd be best as a separate question once you've successfully populated `instance_type` for a single instance per element.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I have raised the count question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768371/how-to-set-the-ec2-resource-instance-count-from-a-map-value-in-a-for-each-in-ter